# Visual Basic.net - BigInt?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

How do I pass a BigInt value to SQL Server?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `BigInt` in SQL Server is equivalent to the `int64` type in VB.NET.

Answer (score 6):

A BigInt in SQL Server is equivalent to the Long type in VB.NET.

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into Table(bigintField) values(42)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store it as a varchar as long as the workload isn't incredibly high.

Comment: Bad habit to take, leads to bad performance as it scales... There is a reason the type exists in the database, the engine does not treat it the same way as a varchar for indexing, collationing, etc..